# How are machine learning diffusion models "learned"?

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood

Let me take as a reference [the paper that introduced diffusion models](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03585.pdf) and let's take as a test case a Gaussian diffusion model.

The reverse trajectory of a Gaussian Markov chain will have the same distributional form as the forward trajectory, thus only the mean and the covariance of the reverse trajectory need to be learned to specify its behavior. Following the notation given in appendix B the reverse diffusion kernel is given by

$$p(x^{(t-1)}| x^{(t)}) = N( x^{(t-1)}; f_{\mu} ( x^{(t)}, t ) , f_{\Sigma} ( x^{(t)}, t ) ) $$

where $f_{\mu} ( x^{(t)}, t ) , f_{\Sigma} ( x^{(t)}, t )$ are two function chosen as multilayer perceptrons (in this case).

The model is then "trained" by optimizing a lower bound $K$ of the loglikelihood $L$ where

$$L = \int d x^{(0)} q( x^{(0)}) \log p( x^{(0)}) $$

and where $q( x^{(0)})$ is the distribution of the (unaltered) data.

Two questions:

1. Why is the model loglikelihood specified as $\int d x^{(0)} q( x^{(0)}) \log p( x^{(0)})$ ? I would have thought that the loglikelihood was only $\log p( x^{(0)})$. How is this integral form of the loglikelihood recovered?
2. Am I correct that the "training" consists of (only) optimizing $K$ wrt to all the parameters used in the multilayer perceptrons $f_{\mu} ( x^{(t)}, t ) , f_{\Sigma} ( x^{(t)}, t )$ ? There is no training set or any labels, we "simply" run an optimization algo on $K$ wrt the parameters used to define $f_{\mu} ( x^{(t)}, t )$ and $f_{\Sigma} ( x^{(t)}, t )$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I agree that the term $\log p(x^{(0)})$ represents the likelihood. However, the equation:

$$L = \int d x^{(0)} q( x^{(0)}) \log p( x^{(0)}) $$

is actually minimising the [cross entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) between $p(x_0)$ and $q(x_0)$. Here, $q(x_0)$ represents the true distribution and $p_\theta(x_0)$ represents the approximated distribution. By minimizing $L_{CE}$, we aim to make the approximated distribution $p_\theta(x_0)$ as close as possible to the true distribution $q(x_0)$. The whole derivation is as follows:

\begin{aligned} 
L_\text{CE} 
&= - \mathbb{E}_{q(\mathbf{x}_0)} \log p_\theta(\mathbf{x}_0) \\ 
&= - \mathbb{E}_{q(\mathbf{x}_0)} \log \Big( \int p_\theta(\mathbf{x}_{0:T}) d\mathbf{x}_{1:T} \Big) \\ 
&= - \mathbb{E}_{q(\mathbf{x}_0)} \log \Big( \int q(\mathbf{x}_{1:T} \vert \mathbf{x}_0) \frac{p_\theta(\mathbf{x}_{0:T})}{q(\mathbf{x}_{1:T} \vert \mathbf{x}_{0})} d\mathbf{x}_{1:T} \Big) \\ 
&= - \mathbb{E}_{q(\mathbf{x}_0)} \log \Big( \mathbb{E}_{q(\mathbf{x}_{1:T} \vert \mathbf{x}_0)} \frac{p_\theta(\mathbf{x}_{0:T})}{q(\mathbf{x}_{1:T} \vert \mathbf{x}_{0})} \Big) \\ 
&\leq - \mathbb{E}_{q(\mathbf{x}_{0:T})} \log \frac{p_\theta(\mathbf{x}_{0:T})}{q(\mathbf{x}_{1:T} \vert \mathbf{x}_{0})} \\ 
&= \mathbb{E}_{q(\mathbf{x}_{0:T})}\Big[\log \frac{q(\mathbf{x}_{1:T} \vert \mathbf{x}_{0})}{p_\theta(\mathbf{x}_{0:T})} \Big] = L_\text{VLB} 
\end{aligned}

However, I believe minimising the likelihood would yield the same variational lower bound in the end. See this [blog](https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2021-07-11-diffusion-models/) for a nice derivation for the loss in diffusion models.

2. Regarding your second question, I'm not sure if I understand it correctly. As you mentioned, the reverse process follows a normal distribution, which is fully defined by its mean and covariance. Hence, we only need to learn the functions $f_{\mu}(x^{(t)}, t)$ and $f_{\Sigma}(x^{(t)}, t)$.

However, in order to learn these parameters, we do require a training set. The parameters are dependent on the data distribution $q(x_0)$ and, therefore, on the dataset we have. It's worth noting that we don't necessarily need labels for the training set.

To perform conditioned generation, where we generate samples based on certain labels or conditions, we do need labels. This allows us to condition the generation process on specific information. You can find more details in the "Conditioned Generation" section of this [blog](https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2021-07-11-diffusion-models/)